# How to solve "target died before we could attach" message in Flutter console?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

i am new to android app development, i just started learning flutter and there is so much information to take in , i downloaded a project from github to try and make sense out the things that i only read about online  and when i run the app this is what i get :

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMzUb.png)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWmhq.png)

in the red boxes you can see there is a lot of things saying " target died before we could attach " what exactly is this ? is it something to be concerned about ?  i tried googling it to see if i find some information about em but i couldn't find anything useful , maybe i was searching it the wrong way ...

**Update**:  After running the "flutter doctor" this is what i got :

C:\src\flutter\flutter>flutter doctor

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.631], locale en-US)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
X Android license status unknown.
Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.

[!] VS Code (version 1.52.0)
X Flutter extension not installed; install from
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

but i am sure that i have installed the flutter and dart plugin

Comment: Please improve the title of your question. I think you could write: "How to solve "target died before we could attach" message in Flutter console?" so it becomes clearer and people already know what your question is about by reading the title

Comment: sorry about that , i changed the  title

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what causes this error but this is how I resolved mine.

1. Confirm that flutter doctor generates no errors.
2. Uninstall any versions of the application from your emulator.
3. flutter run

Now you should be okay.

Answer (score -1):

From a console window that has the Flutter directory in the path, run the following command to see if there are any platform dependencies you need to complete the setup:

```
C:\src\flutter>flutter doctor
```

This command checks your environment and displays a report of the status of your Flutter installation. Check the output carefully for other software you might need to install or further tasks to perform

source [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows)

**# Edit**

If the *doctor* command does not indicate an error, then try to create a new project and copy and paste the classes from the project you downloaded to your new project. Flutter need to download the Gradle, it may be some IDE bug that can be solved by creating a new project

Comment: thanks for pointing me to "flutter doctor" i have updated the main post , i got 3 errors but as for one of the errors regarding the flutter and dart plugin , i am sure that i have installed it after installing the android studio